# Getting the bounding box of each glyph in pdf - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, bounding-box, glyph

I've been trying to highlight text in a pdf. After a lot of research and experiments, it seems like I have to find the bounding box of each glyphs, create an overlay where the actual drawing is happening, and highlight the text by filling the CGRect with the info from bounding box and fill it with color. Now, I am stumped with the bounding box.

I've been using the `PDFKitten` to search and highlight the text. Now I want to use it to select and highlight the text. What I don't understand is how does it use the bounding box ( as well as other information like ascent, descent, capHeight, etc.) to fill highlight the searched word. When I tried to access the `FontDescriptor` class to get the info, it displays this:

```
2012-06-28 16:32:20.626 er[2408:15203] x:-665, y:-325, width:2000, height:1006
2012-06-28 16:32:20.627 er[2408:15203] x:-157, y:-250, width:1126, height:952
2012-06-28 16:32:20.628 er[2408:15203] x:-628, y:-376, width:2000, height:1010
```

It is very confusing so if anyone can clarify this, it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: have you chance to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use font descriptor information to get bounding box for the glyph.

PDFKitten takes care of finding width and height of the each glyph using RenderingState model.

You can use the same to find the location of the word while scanning the PDF.

Font dictionary provides the widths for the glyph. You can use cid to get the correct width of the glyph.

Try to look into highlighting code of the PDFKitten.